# Waiting for something else to finish in native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm playing around with making an audio player with JavaScript and HTML5. Right now I've run into the error that when I try to change the file, and then play it based on the position of a slider, the player.duration is NaN because is hasn't loaded that far yet. If I put in an alert, then it works fine. So basically if the browser is hung up just barely, it gives it enough time, whereas when it runs straight through, it doesn't finish loading in first.

```
player.src = file;
// The next command is reached before the full effect of the above line is finished
player.currentTime = (slider.offsetLeft) / trackWidth * player.duration;
```

There's some other stuff in there, but essentially, I need a way to put just a slight pause in there, or wait for everything to finish before the second line runs. I realize that I could use a setTimeout on the second line, but that line is in the function a couple places, so I was hoping for a "one fix" that I could put after the first line instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to wait for the audio's metadata to become available. This is possible by waiting for the [`loadedmetadata` event](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#event-media-loadedmetadata) and doing the remainder of your code in a callback after that event is fired.

```
player.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    player.currentTime = (slider.offsetLeft) / trackWidth * player.duration;
    // and the remainder of your code relating to the audio element
}, false);
```

The only potential problem with this is that, if the file loads *exceedingly* fast (i.e. it's already in the cache) the event may be fired before the event handler is attached. It may be best to assign the `src` property after adding the event listener.

Comment: @David That should be equivalent, just slightly worse. You could also do `player.onloadedmetadata = func;`

Comment: I tried both of yours before I got to mine. Neither of yours were working.

Comment: @David Did you do `player.onloadedmetadata = func;` or `player.onloadedmetadata = func();`? The first should work; the latter won't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` function to run your code with little delay, eg. 0.5 second.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // your code
}, 500);
```

Also, you can check if player is loaded and if not, set new timeout to wait a bit longer.

Comment: As I said in my post, I'm hoping to not have to do that, as the line it would be needed on is in multiple places in a function, and those make code messy.